# CORS issue with axios post request, does not work with credentials

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, axios, cors

Login code (frontend)

```
const res = await axios.post(config.url, {
   email,
   password
  }, {
    withCredentials: true
})
```

Backend code

(Using cookie-parser)

```
// cookie response
res.cookie("auth-token", token);
```

```
// Express cors middleware

app.use(cors({
  credentials: true
}));
```

The error the browser gives us is
`The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.`

Tried to switch up config, did not work in anyway.

Comment: You need to configure your backend cors middleware such that it sets the Allow-Access-Control-Origin header to whatever the address of your front end is, e.g. Allow-Access-Control-Origin: http://frontend.com. Browsers don’t allow a wildcard (Allow-Access-Control-Origin: *) when withCredentials is true.

Comment: I am testing my frontend on localhost, would that change anything? (My backend is hosted on a container in the cloud)

Comment: It wouldn’t change anything. You’d still have to configure your backend to return an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000 header or whatever.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!